# Show that a system of equations can be solved in terms of $x,y,z$ (Rudin, ex 9.19)

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

(From Principles of Mathematical Analysis, Ch. 9. Ex. 19)

Show that 
$$
\begin{array}{r}
3x + y -z + u^2 = 0 \\
x - y + 2z + u = 0 \\
2x + 2y - 3z + 2u = 0
\end{array}
$$
can be solved in terms of $x,y,z$ but not in terms of $u$.

I know that $u=0,3$ for all solutions.

Say we are trying to solve in terms of $z$. If $u=0$, I have
$$ x = -z/4$$
which I believe is right. However, if $u=3$, I have
$$ x = (-12-z)/z$$
which is **different** from the solutions to Rudin. The solutions indicate that if $u=3$, 
$$ x = (-9-z)/z.$$

Can someone verify which is correct and show the correct answers in terms of $z$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$\begin{array}{r}
3x + y -z + u^2 = 0 \\
x - y + 2z + u = 0 \\
2x + 2y - 3z + 2u = 0
\end{array}
$

Adding the second and third equation,
this becomes

$\begin{array}{r}
3x + y -z + u^2 = 0 \\
3x + y -z + 3u = 0 
\end{array}
$

These two are consistent
only if
$u^2 = 3u$
or
$u = 0$ or $3$.

Comment: Thanks. I understand this part of the question. What I'm not sure about is why x=(-9-z)/z if u=3. Is that the answer you get as well?

Comment: For each value of u, there are two linear equations in three unknowns. This means that any two of the unknowns can be expressed in terms of the other.